# JavaScript define variable outside function

Tags: javascript, html, variables, undefined, nan

I am trying to make a variable which I can keep adding a number to with an html `<input type="number">`.
I want the variable to change with the click of a button with the value of the input. By clicking the button again I want the variable to add the second input to the previously changed number. 
With the following code I get the NaN message with whatever input value because `var num` is undifined:

```
<body>
        <span id="number"></span>
        <input id="addnum" type="number" style="width:60px; height:20px;">
        <button onclick='add()'>Add</button>

    <script>
        var num = 0;

        window.onload = function numstart() {
            document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = num;
        }

        function add() {
            var addnum = parseInt(document.getElementById("addnum").value);
            var num = num + addnum;
            document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = num; 
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

But if I do define `var num = 0;` in the function the number resets each time I call the function. How can I define the variable num in the function without resetting it's value upon calling it?

Comment: Remove the "var" inside the function; the word "var" basically means "make a new variable" which is clearly not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You are resetting `num` in your `add()` function, and it doesn't make much sense:

```
var num = num+addnum;
```

means "make a new variable num, whose value is num+addnum, but wait, you just defined num, so..."

You want to reference the global var. Try this:

```
num += addnum;
```

or

```
num = num+addnum;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
<body>
    <span id="number"></span>
    <input id="addnum" type="number" style="width:60px; height:20px;">
    <button onclick='add()'>Add</button>

<script>
    var num = 0;

    window.onload = function numstart() {
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = num;
    }

    function add() {
        var addnum = parseInt(document.getElementById("addnum").value);
        num = num + addNum;
        document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = num; 
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is tricky [**hoisting**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) thing happening which confuses you. Your code is equivalent to this:

```
function add() {
    var addnum = parseInt(document.getElementById("addnum").value);
    var num;

    num = num + addnum;
    document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = num; 
}
```

Now it's obvious why `num` is undefined within function block, `num` is declared but not *defined* so it's `undefined`, and local declaration shadows outer `num`. So you get `NaN` of course.

The fix is simple, just remove `var` keyword to work directly with outer scope `num`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>    
        function add() {                
            document.getElementById('number').innerHTML =  parseInt(document.getElementById('number').innerHTML)+1; 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <span id="number"></span>
        <input id="addnum" type="number" style="width:60px; height:20px;">
        <button onclick='add()'>Add</button>       
</body>
</html>
```

You're having this problem because everytime you click, your function starts all over again then finishes, and releasing its allocated memory spaces.